# how can I get UTF8 characters from word?

Tags: mysql, ms-word

I have some words in Devnagri language which I am able to type by setting appropriate font in word.
I want to save data in mysql database.
I set my mysql database to UTF8.
when I copy and paste some string (in same language) from web and insert it into db it works fine.
but when I copy string from word it gives garbage.
I know issue is with encoding but was not able to resolve it.
any guideline is most welcome in this regard.

Comment: How do you type the characters, and which font do you use then? There are no “UTF8 characters”. UTF-8 is a transfer coding for Unicode, and MS Word does not use it internally. It sounds like you are using a font trick, with a privately encoded font. Converting data written using it requires exact information about the private encoding.

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question. If you were, for example, using Apache POI to read the word doc, it might be.

Comment: It was regarding how I can get UTF-8 encoded characters rather than windows encoding.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

MS Word seems to be using a proprietary character set, which is incompatible with UTF8. If you really must paste from MS Word, have a look at this page which describes how to export your word document as HTML page with the correct encoding and other options.
http://www.ljmu.ac.uk/ITHelp/webpublishing/118183.htm

Open the generated page or document and try pasting from there.

Comment: Modern versions of MSword use UTF-16 inside all the time, not proprietary encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Word has a lot of stuff underneath that when copied (font size, font family, whether is underline, bold, underlined, etc..) get pasted as "garbage".

To avoid this, copy the text from word, paste it on "notepad" (if you're on windows) or "TextEdit" if you're on Mac (If on mac, make sure to select "Format -> Make Plain text").
Then copy the text from here and paste it on your mysql database.